# Overlapping features in index layer of Map Series in ArcGIS Pro show even when not currently selected

Tags: arcgis-pro, map-series

I am using the Map Series tool in ArcGIS Pro to create about 30 maps using "Florida BMAPs" as the index layer. Some of the features in this layer overlap. I assumed this wouldn't be an issue, because the Map Series tool would only display the selected index layer feature per map layout. However, what is actually happening is anywhere that adjacent BMAP boundaries coincide with the current selected BMAP feature, they are also being displayed. It is hard to ignore this error, since the line width for the unwanted features is even bolder than the correct boundary.

Is there any way I can fix this so that only the desired BMAP boundary is being selected & displayed?

In the image below, you can see the desired BMAP boundary is a thin black line in a oval shape surrounding the other polygons. I've circled the undesired lines (resulting from other overlapping BMAP boundaries) in RED.

[image: BMAP boundaries]

Answer (score 1):

If you go to layer properties you can change the Page Query. if you select an unique atribute only the selected Map Series Feature will be shown

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to right click layout in the map series pages content pane to open the layout properties window, and select clip to index feature under map extent, although you wont see anything except the selected feature (see map example).
[image]